# call dictionary from one sub to another in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dictionary

I'm stuck with a problem when I'm working with a dictionary in VBA. The reason why I want to work with a dictionary and a do-while loop is because I have variables with different length, that I want to loop through.
First I want to give the dic keys and and items.
The reason why I skip one col for each loop is because each series has a col with dates and then a col with prices. If it is possible I want to capture the dates that match the prices in the same dictionary.

```
Sub opg1(dicSPX As Object)

    Dim i As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim varColLeng As Variant

    Set dicSPX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    m = 10

    Sheets("Data").Activate
    
    ReDim intCol(1 To nCol)
   'opretter dictionary
    ReDim n(1 To m)
    Do While n <> ""
        For i = 1 To mn
'            redim preserve IntColLen
            dicSPX.Add Cells(1, 2 + ((i - 1) * 2)).Value, Range(Cells(9, 2 + ((i - 1) * 2)), Cells(n, 2 + ((i - 1) * 2))).Value
        Next i
    Loop
End Sub
```

then I want to execute a procedure for all keys in my dic. I want to compute returns in different time series.
However, when I call the dic, to the sub Returns() I get an error (Compile error: Variable not defined). I'm new to dictionaries and I probably missed a small detail.

```
Sub Returns()

    Call opg1(dicSPX)
    
    Dim dicSPX As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim varKey As Variant, varArr As Variant
    
    For Each varKey In dicSPX
        varArr = dicSPX(varKey)
        For i = LBound(varArr, 1) To UBound(varArr, 1)
            For j = LBound(varArr, 2) To UBound(varArr, 2)
'                varReturns(i,j) = compute  the return here
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Any suggestions? I hope the question is clear.

Thank you

Comment: Lots of undeclared variables: `nFonde`, `nCol`.

Comment: You are using `Call opg1(dicSPX)` then defining  `dicSPX` on the next line

Comment: `Do While n <> ""` is a Type Mismatch.

Comment: Thank you @VincentG. 
But when I comment it out VBA still give me the same error

Comment: As @Vincent G says, move the `Call opg1(dicSPX)` to after the `Dim` statements

Comment: Thank you @BigBen.
VBA gives me the error and marks "dicSPX" in Call opg1(dicSPX)

Comment: opg1 create the object, but you need to put the definition before the call. and you don't need `New` since, again, opg1 uses `CreateObject` to create it.

Comment: The title of this question is nonsense. Please use a more descriptive title in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be clear which variable is not defined by the line which is highlighted after the error is thrown. At a quick glance I can tell that you didn't define `i` or `j`:

```
Sub Returns()
    Dim dicSPX As New Scripting.Dictionary
    opg1(dicSPX)
        
    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In dicSPX
        Dim varArr As Variant
        varArr = dicSPX(varKey)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(varArr, 1) To UBound(varArr, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(varArr, 2) To UBound(varArr, 2)
                varReturns(i,j) = compute  the return here
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

You should always explicitly define each variable, one line at a time, right before they are used. This way the declaration is always near the usage so you can see it on the same page.

You should also make `opg1` a function that returns a dictionary. That would clarify your intent. Passing a variable by reference makes it harder to tell how the program works to the reader.